# Customizing TI Sensor Tag

Tags: android

I am developing a custom IoT application using TI Sensor Tag. For that I don't need all the sensors, and probably need only the Mag Sensor.

I have already figured out the way to enable disable unwanted sensors on the mobile apps provided by TI.

But I would like to know if there is any guide that helps me to design the sensor tag by removing the other sensors, and still have the capability to flash.

I am looking at CC2541 (I2C sensor interfacing).

Please help me out if you have any pointers and thanks in advance.